# Is there a Widget which allows to switch implementation depending on platform?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to find a widget which would return specific platform (Cupertino or Material) implementation e.g. **CupertinoPageScaffold** vs **Scaffold** or **CupertinoNavigationBar** vs **AppBar**

Is there anything like that before I create abstract PlatformWidget?

Answer (score 1):

There's no widget that integrate both Material and Cupertino design into one place.

But honestly, you shouldn't. Their API may be radically different. And you'll have a real hard time to fuse both. 
Especially considering you can do a `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()` for example.

What is recommended instead is to use `Theme.of(context).platform` to choose which layout you want to instantiate. And create two separate layout, one for each OS.

Comment: I've noticed that some classes share API while others are different. I am looking for a way to avoid duplicating UI and automating some mundane tasks e.g. on iOS set style on Text() to body1. I have created abstract widget to handle that its just I am surprised nothing like this is in the SDK

Comment: `some mundane tasks e.g. on iOS set style on Text() to body1`  But you don't have to. There's a widget called `DefaultTextStyle`  which you can set to whatever you want for this purpose.

Comment: Flutter wants to avoid 'compat libraries' at all cost. Doing such thing would be going backward.